# Adding a existing developed site to a multisite installation of WordPress

Tags: multisite, migration, import

Let's suppose I have a website *www.abc.com*, which is a blog and shop website. Then I have another website, which is *www.xyz.com*, on which I have created a network multisite, where *xyz.com* is the networks main site. I want to add *abc.com* website to the network of the *xyz.com* website, so I can handle the administration via the same super admin, backend. I can see the option of creating a new website in multisite admin, but not to add a already developed website. Is that possible to add a existing site to a multisite?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to import or migrate the data or site. IT all depends on your premises and needs.

As a first option, there is of course the [WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/), which often does the job, but isn't the most diverse tool there is.

If you're comfortable with [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) – if not, you should, because the convenience of WP-CLI is just amazing –, then there is another great option for more complex cases, it's the [MU-Migration](https://github.com/10up/MU-Migration) plugin for WP-CLI, some additional information can be found at this [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/wordpress-multisite-migrations/). It really does a great job in migrating single sites to a multisite, or moving subsites between networks.